# Routing nginx in GAE flex env

Tags: php, google-app-engine, nginx

I'm new to GAE and Nginx, this should be pretty simple but I've spent quite a bit of time with no luck, so here I am.

I'm trying to route requests to the correct location in my Google App Engine PHP Flex environment. The folder structure of my app looks something like this:

```
├── api
│   └── public
│       └── rest
├── app.yaml
├── composer.json
└── public
    ├── app1
    └── app2
```

And my app.yaml looks like:

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: public
  enable_stackdriver_integration: true
```

I'd like to be able to do an ajax request from each of the app folders to the API public folder with the url looking something like example.com/api/some_file.php. Also I'd like to route any calls to api/public/rest to a router file.

I tried adding a nginx-http.conf file to the project root that looks like:

```
server {
    location ^~ /api/ {
        alias /api/public/;
    }

    location ^~ /api/rest/ {
        try_files $uri /routes.php;
    }
}
```

But just get a 404. Any guidance here would be appreciated!

To clarify:
First; How do I route requests to a folder outside of the document root (while still executing the php script)?
Second; How do I redirect all request of a particular URL to a single php router files for rest requests?

Comment: You provide scarce information about what you want to do. Could you provide some more insight about the issue? How do you perform your AJAX requests? Have you tried it locally before deploying the app?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, App Engine accepts two ways to route your request: either use the default routing rules for requests with a URL that ends at the domain level, or prepare a dispatch file that routes specific URL patterns according to your rules. In this case, you want to use the second option if I’m correct. In this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/how-requests-are-routed) there is more information about request routing.

To use the dispatch file (dispatch.yaml), you have to configure by indicating the URL where the route requests come from and the service to which the requests will be sent. You can have more information about the dispatch file in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/dispatchref).

Once you define the routing dispatch file, store it in your project root and deploy your PHP app. I would recommend trying it first locally before deploying it to App Engine.

Comment: That seems to be for routing between services. I only have one service at the moment.

Comment: Have you checked how the app is identified on the outside? That way you can get the right URLs to handle on the other side. (This may come in [handy](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/appidentity/#asserting_identity_to_third-party_services)).